# VB 6 to VB.NET equivalent of Synchronize Access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

Need to convert this VB6 code to VB.NET 2005. Using Access 2007.
Have searched all over and can't seem to find the correct method.
TIA

Here is the VB6 code:

```
Dim DBS As Database 
DBS.Synchronize "C:\ExQC.mdb", dbRepExportChanges
```

Comment: Can you tell us what this did in VB6?  I used to be a VB6/Access developer but this method does not ring a bell and it is very hard to find information about this on the web.

Comment: Probably this module in the project itself

Comment: Synchronize is similiar (in my understanding) to SQL Replication. Aparently VB6 had a method to do this. It appears Microsoft added this feature to Access where it doesnt even need to be done programatically. If you cant do it that way... I guess you will have to do it manually. Where you open 2 datasets and compare the 2 and update one when the other changes. Not really a nice 1 line solution like the above shows.

Comment: Try this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/93f858b3-fa51-4cea-8836-664517e6b52a/synchronize-replicated-access-database-using-vbnet?forum=Offtopic

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure what it used to do. I've been asked to convert the VB6 to VB.NET and I'm lost on it.